# Outgoing calls from vtiger to an asterisk extension

Tags: asterisk, crm

I've successfully installed vtiger and asterisk on Ubuntu, and I managed to configure them such that I get an incoming and an outgoing popup in vtiger. The problem is that when I click on an extension in vtiger to call another soft phone using SIP it shows me the outgoing popup saying `Pick up the extensions receiver to dial the number`. However my soft phone doesn't ring or allow me to pick up the receiver.

I'm not sure what the problem is. When another soft phone calls my extension and I pick it up then I do get the incoming popup in vtiger. The problem is only with outgoing calls. I get the popup but I can't make the call. The most annoying part is that I don't get any error logs in my asterisk cli terminal or anywhere else I can think of. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Asterisk Extension in your vtiger User Preferences. See the vtiger wiki for [complete configuration instructions](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/PBX_Manager_Module).

Comment: I did that but the call isn't being forwarded to my extension.

Comment: @AaditMShah how did you fix the problem ? I'm getting call to extension but when I pickup it just does nothing and showing popup "Pick up the extensions receiver to dial the number"

Answer (score 1):

I would try to have it append a # to the end of the number when dialing a local extension. So for instance if your extension is 1234 have the system dial 1234#.

Comment: I tried to do so to no avail.